# should the asymptote be apart of a rational function when graphed

Tags: functions, asymptotics, transformation, rational-functions

on a recent math test in Pre Cal 12 which I would have gotten perfect if it weren't for the .5 marks I lost on a question appeared a problem which asked me to draw the image of a function after certain transformations are applied to it. The image appeared to be a rational function. I labeled the asymptotes and intercepts to help me better sketch the graph, however I did not draw the asymptotes on the graph grid; I lost .5 marks for that even though I specified the asymptote equations under the question AND the question DID NOT SPECIFY to DRAW the asymptotes on the graph grid. Please answer me how is this marking justified?

Comment: You should draw the asymptotes anyway since it helps to give the graph its shape. Also - calm down. It's just half a point.

Comment: The person who can tell you how the marking is justified is the person who did the marking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asymptote isn't a "part" of the graph. It's moreso a property of it: that the limit as the graph approaches a point approaches a certain value but never reaches it. Though as was noted in a comment, it is also a graphing tool, somewhat.

I imagine the marks were taken off because the asymptote is precisely that property. It was likely only 0.5 marks taken off because it's sort of a technicality: after all, if you already know the asymptotes, why bother? But it's still cutting corners at the pre-calculus level, thus some amount had to be taken off.

Comment: when i talked to the teacher, he said that the asymptotes are "part" of the graph ITSELF. My argument would be if one was to graph the function on a graphing calculator, the calculator would not draw the asymptotes thus they are not part of the graph

Comment: Graphing calculators are not the Supreme Court of Mathematics. Anyway, it seems that you now know how the marking is justified, as you have heard the justification from the actual marker. So there really isn't any point to your question, is there?

Comment: @anonymous According to Wikipedia, the [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function) is a set of ordered pairs $(x, f(x))$ (so, formally, it's exactly the same as the function $f$ itself). If you want to get picky, then, according to this definition, the claim that asymptotes are a part of the graph is incorrect. There is no sense in which, say, the point $(0, -1)$ on the vertical asymptote of $y = 1/x$ belongs to the set of points $(x, 1/x)$.